# jquery: how to include other .js-files into .js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, include, external

Is there any jquery plugin (instead of incldeMany) or simple function to include js-files on demand ?

for example:

```
$.include('myscript.js');
```

?

Answer (score 63):

How about [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)? It's built in to jQuery and works like so:

```
$.getScript('ajax/test.js', function() {
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: Note: the path is relative to the root folder, not where the jQuery file is. So, if you have a main file for your functions like site.com/assets/main.js and you use this function to load in "test.js" the function would be: 

$.getScript('assets/test.js', function() {
     alert('Load was performed.');
});

or wherever you've got the file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @DrewDelloStritto The path is not relative to the root folder but to the folder where the browser called html file is. So if you load site.com/assets/page.html and the main script is in site.com/assets/main.js than to load test in the same folder you need `$.getScript('test.js', function() { alert('Load was performed.'); });`

Comment: Note that `alert()` might not always be fired. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19819672/13019 for a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a jQuery plugin, but you might try looking into [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).  Especially the "[How to use RequireJS with jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)" section.

I don't have much experience with this solution yet, but from what I've read and played around with I like the possibilities.