# Create new object instance away from it's constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, instance

So I wan't to preview some UI effects without the user having to refresh their client. I thought of doing this by creating a new instance of my `Anim` object which is defined using a plain simple constructor.

```
function Anim(elem) {
  this.elem = elem
}

Amin.prototype.zoomIn = function() {
 // Do stuff
},

Amin.prototype.zoomOut = function() {
 // Do stuff
}

// obj is a jQuery object, like $('div');
var instance = new Anim(obj);
```

So far so good, but how do I create a new instance of an object away from it's constructor?

This is in a different file, trying to create a new instance just for the sake of previewing it to the user. I'm receiving an error telling me that:

> Anim is not defined

I get that it's out of scope, but how do I make it available?

```
$('span').on('click', function() {
    new Anim( $('div') );
});
```

Comment: So `Anim` is out of scope... How are you including the first file?

Comment: Anim is defined as a plugin, no namespace, separate file.

Comment: Make sure `Anim` is accessible from whatever scope your other file is in, and also `Anim` is defined at the time when `new Anim` is being executed.

Comment: @piggypig: What "plugin" are you talking about? A jQuery plugin? What pattern does it use? Please show the complete file and how you load it.

Comment: If you include both files in your HTML via `<script>` tags, try including the Anim file **before** the second one. Otherwise, maybe loading the script like this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2598540/921486

Comment: But since it being an object, not defined inside a any other function scope or namespace object, shouldn't it be available in the global scope and therefor callable now?

Comment: @Bergi, It's literally as simple as shown above, no jQuery widget pattern, just a constructor, what's inside the methods doesn't matter. Could be as simple as an alert telling the user what effect was chosen.

Comment: @Bergi. I can't post it all, if wan't an exact example, have a look at [this Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/alert.js) plugin, my plugin is using the same "pattern".

Comment: @piggypig: That *is* a jQuery plugin. It's not "just" a constructor, the constructor is in an IEFE scope that makes it invisible to the outside. You're not creating a global variable there

Comment: @bergi,  You're right, I wasn't thinking clear and didn't write that part in my own plugin yet. When done it's a jQuery plugin, which makes it way easier. I'll make it so I can do $('div').anim('zoomIn') since that will be attached to jQuery prototype, which is in scope. Cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach here is to define your `Anim` object as a Module, take a look at **[AMD (Asynchronus Module Definition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)**, then you can just import our js file everywhere and use new instances of your object:

```
define(function(){
    var Anim = function(elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.zoomIn = function() {
           // Do stuff
        };

        this.zoomOut = function() {
           // Do stuff
        }
    }
    return Anim;
});
```

Put it in afile call it `Anim.js`.

Then just include this file in your HTML page or in any other JS file and create new instances of `Anim` object:

```
define([pathToyourFile.Anim],function(Anim){
    $('span').on('click', function() {
        var instance = new Anim( $('div') );
    });
});
```

For further information about **AMD modules**, take a look at:

- **[The power of the Asynchronous Module Definition](http://www.2ality.com/2011/10/amd.html)**.
- **[Dojo - Introduction to AMD Modules](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/)**.
- **[Writing Modular JavaScript With AMD, CommonJS & ES Harmony](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)**

Comment: Awesome, this approach make total sense. Going to work this out, thanks!

Comment: Great glad it helps, yes indeed it's very powerful, and almost all new JavaScript librairies are based on it.