# How to load a script on $(document).ready()/onDeviceReady() of jquery-mobile/phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an application using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.

Now when the page gets loaded then I want to load a `script(.js file)`. Basically `onDeviceReady` or `$(document).ready()`. How to do that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
//wait for document.ready to fire
$(function () {

    //then load the JavaScript file
    $.getScript('script.js');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript

```
//create a callback function
function myCallback () {


    //create a script element and set it's type and async attributes
    var script = document.createElement('script'); script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.async = true;

    //set the source of the script element
    script.src = 'script.js';


    //add the script element to the DOM
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);

}

//add event listener for the deviceready function to run our callback function
document.addEventListener("deviceready", myCallback, false);
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready

This second code snippet is a slightly modified version of the Google Analytic code, used to add a script to the DOM asynchronously.

**UPDATE**

You can also set the `defer` attribute of a `<script>` tag to `true` and it won't be executed until after the DOM has been prepared. See some documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Script

Comment: Thanks Jasper.Answer is Precise...:D

Comment: I, too, was experiencing the problem where IE8 was breaking on refresh.  Using the $(document).ready() call is what fixed it for me. Thx for the answer!

Comment: NB: getScript is asynchronous so calling a function declared within the called script may result in "undefined" errors. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130921/is-the-callback-on-jquerys-getscript-unreliable-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong

Comment: @Costa The `$.getScript` method also has a callback parameter you can use.

Comment: @Jasper the callback runs when the code is **loaded**, not when the code is **executed**, so it's not reliable