# jQuery getScript() sometimes works fine, sometimes returns "parsererror" and TypeError Exception

Tags: jquery, ajax, getscript

I have strange problem with jQuery (currently 1.9.1 version), I am using getScript() function to load some additional JS library on demand. It loads everytime the same library from the same libraries, so there is no difference between multiple requests. It is always returned from server as "application/javascript". I use only one browser for these requests.

```
$.getScript(scripts[s], function(){
  onScriptLoaded();
}).done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log(textStatus);
}).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  console.log(jqxhr, settings, exception);
});
```

It usually runs fine, `.done()` is called and textStatus is `success`. However, about 1 in 10 requests, it fails and `.fail()` is called - `settings` contains `parsererror` and `exceoption` contains `TypeError {}`.

I really have no idea why is this happening, because 9 times out of 10 it works fine. But why it sometimes fails, I really don't know. Can anybody shed some light on this problem ?

I will be glad for any hints or help.

Comment: are you calling scripts from the same server or different

Comment: Check the network traffic in Firebug and have a look at the statuscode. My guess would be some kind of 500 server error somewhere

Comment: I have checked that previously in Developer tools, server always returns the right file with 200 OK and with correct Content-Type

Comment: And in a comment on my now-deleted answer, Frodik says that when the error occurs, he's even checked the content sent back by comparing MD5 hashes! So something Very Weird Is Going On.

Comment: I suspect you are suffering from premature evaluation. $.getScript uses $.get and then parses. I think the browser is signalling completion before the buffer is ready. If that's the case then yielding before parsing should fix it. Modifying jQuery is a bit extreme but you could test the idea by using get and eval directly in your code and using setTimeout to call eval thereby giving XHR a chance to finish marshalling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution, but I am not happy with it, because I don't know the real cause of this problem.

I used solution mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068597/385264

It's not really an answer, because I have no idea, what and why is going on. I am glad that I got it to work, but I would like if someone could explain it.

I hope, at least, it will help someone with similar problem.